# Is there a way to indicate you want only long articles in Google News?

Tags: google-news

When I click on news articles at news.google.com, I often get taken to "articles" which only have two paragraphs of text.

**Is there a way to tell Google News that I only want it to show me links to articles of e.g. 5 paragraphs or more?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and simple: no, there is no way this can be directly done. In Google News, you can filter news based on topic, date, the website the news is posted on but nothing on the number of paragraphs posted in the news.

One thing that you can do is find particular news websites which give detailed news and filter your Google News results to show news from only these providers.